# Hats unexpectedly resize when being moved

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Inside the WB 2021 pop-up where you can manage the placement of the hats, when moving the hat towards the boundary of the profile picture, it resizes in an awkward manner. It even resizes more than needed to stay within its boundaries. Also, it re-resizes when you drag it back towards the center (without releasing the mouse). Is this behavior intended?

Note that I do *not* mean dragging the handle meant for resizing the hat. I mean grabbing and moving the hat itself.

It may be better just to block movement of the hat and make it stick at its current position when it reaches the limit instead of automatically resizing it, because this makes placement of the hat quite difficult.

Also, I find this behavior quite counterituitive: Dragging something should only move the item and not resize it. And dragging a handle that indicates that it is for moving should probably also not resize at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Ideally one would resize while the other would move/rotate, but unfortunately both resize even when resizing is not what we want.