# Hat scale controls are too sensitive

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The hat scale controls are too sensitive for me. The whole scale range is mapped to ~13 pixels of control movement.

For example, here's the minimal scale I can set:

[image: pic]

And here's the maximal scale, achieved by moving the blue circle just 13 pixels higher.

[image: pic]

Comment: The problem that both handles in some situations scale the hat adds to this problem. See [Hats unexpectedly resize when being moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374108/1112702)

Comment: Put your finger or mouse on the control, make a small circular movement. Now you are exactly (or very close to) where you started, and have *grab* on the control, with the ability to make additional small movements until you release it.